# Do something while subprocesses are working?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Is there a way to do something like printing stuff or converting a manager dict to a local dict in the main process in case of a keyboard interrupt while joining subprocesses:

Something like:

```
def joinProcesses(self,processes):
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
        print('Evaluation Process finished')

while self.joinProcesses(processes):
    time.sleep(2)
    print('test')
    self.fixedResults = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(self.results)
```

I want to save the updated results in a manager dict periodly in a local dict in case of a keyboard interrupt. Furthermore I want to print performance of the evalulations of the subprocesses while they are running

This example would not work I think because it waits until all subprocesses are finished

Answer (score 2):

A join is how you *wait* for a process to complete. Just do whatever you want *before* calling join.

```
# start processes
self.fixedResults = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(self.results)
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

Comment: yeah but the results are created in the subprocesses. rows in a a manager dict. The should be saved in periods in a local dict to prevent a disconnect to the manager dict from a keyboard interrupt. Furthermore I want perfoirmance prints of the subrpocess evaluations while they are working. So I have to do something in a while loop, arent I?

Comment: I don't know, because you haven't shown anything that the subprocesses are doing. If you are really asking about how to *communicate* between multiple processes, you'll need to include that in the question.

Comment: yeah you are right. The communication of main and subprocesses is the keyword. But Im new to this topic. I starting sum multiprocessing.Process subproceesses. But everywhere I just read something about subprocess.Popen. Is it also possible to communicate with the multiprocessing.Process subprocesses?

Comment: `Popen` uses an explicit fork-and-exec model which lets you execute non-Python code in a subprocess. The `multiprocessing` library simply forks your current process into multiple processes (no exec is involved). The module provides things like `Queue` and `Pipe` for passing data between two processes.

Comment: Ok this is interesting. And If I want to catch something like a sys.stoudt from a multiprocessing.Process in the main process? I just wonder If there is something like a True State of the multiprocessing.Process processes, so that I can periodicly update or catch some outputs in the main process

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using standard output to communicate between the two. That unnecessarily sends data out of the process on a file handle, only to have to capture it and read it back in. A `multiprocess.Pipe` is probably what you want.